# expression for Dirichlet's kernel like sum

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

It is given in the book that the Dirichlet's kernel $D_n(t) = 1/2 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \cos(kt)$ is given as $\frac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{2\sin(t/2)}$. I'd like to know if there is any such expression for  $1/2 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sin(kt)$ which is obtained by giving a $\pi/2$ shift for terms $D_n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in A.P ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-a-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more natural to consider this sum without $1/2$. It will be a conjugate function to 
the Dirichlet's kernel: 
$$
\sum _{k=1}^n \sin (k x)=\csc \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{n x}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2}
   (n+1) x\right).
$$